# struggling with prepared statement for select query

Tags: php, prepared-statement

In a php file responding to an Ajax request, I'm trying to use prepared statements instead of doing it this way (actually working):

```html
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','pokemons');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM pokemons_en WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    $separator = '|';
        
    echo '<img src="'. $row['image'] .'" unselectable="on"/>' . $separator . $row['name'] . $separator.  $row['type'] . $separator . $row['categorie'] . $separator. $row['talent']. $separator. $row['taille']. $separator. $row['poids']. $separator . '<audio id="audio" src="'. $row['audio'] .'" ></audio>'. $separator . $row['type2']. $separator . $row['bio'] ;

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is the file outputing data from mySQL database and it is actually working. But from what I understood I really should use prepared statements for performence reasons and also in order to prevent SQL injection attacks.

I tried with this and many other methods I could found but I can't get it working. What part should I correct/ modify ?

```html
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "pokemons";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pokemons_en WHERE id = '".$q."'"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    while($row = $stmt->fetchAll()) { 
        
        $separator = '|';
        
    echo '<img src="'. $row['image'] .'" unselectable="on"/>' . $separator . $row['name'] . $separator.  $row['type'] . $separator . $row['categorie'] . $separator. $row['talent']. $separator. $row['taille']. $separator. $row['poids']. $separator . '<audio id="audio" src="'. $row['audio'] .'" ></audio>'. $separator . $row['type2']. $separator . $row['bio'] ;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: id = '".$q."' in prepared statements?

Comment: False, it means you don&#39;t understand how prepared statements work. Read first some doc. Start by placing question marks where the parameters go.

Comment: If you are expecting one result, use [$stmt->fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) -- in addition to user3783243's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50612944/1022914)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables don't go in prepared statements. Try:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pokemons_en WHERE id = ?"); 
$stmt->execute(array($q));
```

The `?` is a placeholder the driver will escape it and quote it as needed. The `execute` binds the value into the query.